# Android emulator doesn't work

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-emulator

I am new to Xamarin and trying to run the '*Hello, Android*' application found in the introductory chapter of the official on-line Xamarin guide (link [**here**](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/)). I use `Visual Studio Community 2017 (VS)`.

I've created an `Android Virtual Device (AVD)` using Visual Studio's `Android Emulator Manager` tool. Here's a screenshot of the settings of the AVD I've set up:

[image]

My hardware specs are: Intel Core2 Duo 8400, 5GB of DDR2 667MHz RAM. I also use Win10 Enterprise.

Now, when try to run my application I initiate the AVD from within VS and *after waiting for at least 5 minutes* get the following screenshot from the Android Emulator:

[image]

How can I troubleshoot this error? As it is right now I simply cannot debug any Android application using Visual Studio and the specs described above.

**Update:**

I installed the exact same software on my laptop. The hardware specs of the laptop are: Core I5 4210U, 12GB DDR3 1600MHz.

Now the emulator runs smoothly, but, although I installed the *same software* I get a *different* GUI for the AVD. Anyway, problem solved. It seems the low hardware specifications was the issue.

[image]

**Update 2:**

It seems the AVD has problems. The build process intermittently halts at this point:

> 1 >  Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
>
> 1 >  Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml

Also the sample application I tried to deploy (when the AVD starts) doesn't work.

Comment: The hardware specs of your computer are pretty low (that is the reason you wait for at least 5 minutes) but have you tried increasing the RAM of the virtual device? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Have you enable "the Inter Virtual Technology"?

Comment: @YorkShen Yes, I have. This was done in the BIOS.

Comment: If possible, deploy on a  actual device will be best. If not, you could use a better machine try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com) is an Android emulator that is free for personal use. It is what I use and it works very well. I would recommend trying that.

Comment: I ended up using Genymotion. It runs considerably faster compared to the AVD created by Android SDK. It also runs without any problems (so far).

Answer (score 0):

Install Intel HAXM and enable `Use Host GPU` in AVD properties

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've already done the first and cannot do the second one because my system does not allow it.